# sqlite3 cannot find -lsqlite3

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm using raspberry pi 2B with raspbian lite.

I'm trying to add an sqlite3 library on my C++ program.
Without starting adding any piece of code, using the flag -lsqlite3 I get the error.

```
src/main.cpp src/radio/radio.cpp src/radio/sx1276/sx1276.cpp src/file_manager/file_manager.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -lwiringPi -l sqlite3 -o lora src/main.cpp src/radio/radio.cpp src/radio/sx1276/sx1276.cpp src/file_manager/file_manager.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I have installed the sqlite3 on my system.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install sqlite3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
sqlite3 is already the newest version (3.16.2-5+deb9u1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-filesystem1.58.0 libboost-program-options1.58.0 libboost-system1.58.0 libboost-thread1.58.0 libboost-thread1.62.0 libmongoclient-dev libmongoclient0 libpcap0.8 libpcrecpp0v5 libsnappy1v5 libv8-3.14.5 mongodb-clients
  mongodb-dev mongodb-server
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Have you installed `libsqlite3-dev`?

Comment: no, I have not.

Comment: That seems to be your answer.  Library not found because library is not present. https://packages.debian.org/sid/libsqlite3-dev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to link an SQLite3 program you need the `libsqlite3` (run-time) and `libsqlite3-dev` (development) libraries installed.

Install those with `sudo apt install libsqlite-dev` (which will pull in the run-time dependency).

Comment: `sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev` worked for me. It looks like `libsqlite-dev` has been removed from apt packages.